# Move cursor slowly delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Good day ... I'm moving the cursor with the mouse:

```
SetCursorPos (Source2 [1], source3 [1]);
```

But I need this to move slowly ... as if a person was moving the mouse up ... For the way I do it comes out from one point to another on the screen:

```
0: SetCursorPos (Source2 [1], source3 [1]); 
  1: SetCursorPos (Source2 [2], source3 [2]); 
  2: SetCursorPos (Source2 [3], source3 [3]); 
  3: SetCursorPos (Source2 [4], source3 [4]); 
  4: SetCursorPos (Source2 [5], source3 [5]); 
  5: SetCursorPos (Source2 [6], source3 [6]); 
  6: SetCursorPos (Source2 [7], source3 [7]); 
  7: SetCursorPos (Source2 [8], source3 [8]); 
  8: SetCursorPos (Source2 [9], source3 [9]); 
  9: SetCursorPos (Source2 [10], source3 [10]); 
  10: SetCursorPos (Source2 [11], source3 [11]); 
  11: SetCursorPos (Source2 [12], source3 [12]); 
  12: SetCursorPos (Source2 [13], source3 [13]); 
  13: SetCursorPos (Source2 [14], source3 [14]); 
  14: SetCursorPos (Source2 [15], source3 [15]); 
  15: SetCursorPos (Source2 [16], source3 [16]); 
  16: SetCursorPos (Source2 [17], source3 [17]); 
  17: SetCursorPos (Source2 [18], source3 [18]); 
  18: SetCursorPos (Source2 [19], source3 [19]); 
  19: SetCursorPos (Source2 [20], source3 [20]);
```

You can move the mouse cursor, as if it had an effect ... a move slowly from one point to another??

Comment: Take a timer and move at each timer tick. What is your question about ?

Comment: I'm understanding ... Every 0005 milliseconds I make the mouse move 1px 1px X and Y ...

Comment: Are you wanting your mouse point to always move in a straight line from x1, y1 to x2, y2? If so, you should take a look at the [LineDDA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145025(v=vs.85).aspx) API function. You should be able to google examples on how to use it in Delphi. It maps the points along a straight line.

Comment: You could always use `Sleep`. Can't believe I just said that. But what's the point of handling input if you are going to ignore it. So in this case perhaps you want to avoid processing all input. If you want good help though, you need to provide some context. Why are you doing this most unusual thing in the first place? If you told us that we might be able to give you sound advice.

Answer (score 4):

Using an anonymous thread.

This will at least avoid a `Sleep()` call.

```
Uses
  SyncObjs;

procedure MoveSlow( const X,Y : TArray<Integer>);
var
  anonT : TThread;
  XX,YY : TArray<Integer>;
begin
  // Only local variables are captured
  XX := x;  
  YY := y;
  anonT := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      w : TSimpleEvent;
      i : Integer;
    begin
      w := TSimpleEvent.Create(Nil,False,False,'');
      Try
        for i := Low(XX) to High(XX) do begin
          TThread.Synchronize(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              SetCursorPos(XX[i],YY[i]);
            end
          );
          w.WaitFor(10);
        end;
      Finally
        w.Free;
      end;
    end
  );
  anonT.Start;  // anonT will self terminate by default
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x,y : TArray<Integer>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(x,100);
  SetLength(y,100);
  for i := Low(x) to High(x) do
    x[i] := Self.Left + i*(Self.Width div 100);
  for i := Low(y) to High(y) do
    y[i] := Self.Top + i*(Self.Height div 100);
  MoveSlow(x,y);
end;
```

The slow move of the cursor will be handled by the anonymous thread, which every 10 ms will send a synchronized `SetCursorPos()` to the GUI.

---

Turns out that I wrote an animation class based on a timer, [`Tricky thing about pointers to animate something in Delphi`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15323125/576719). **Note** that for a `TTimer` the smallest delay is about 10 ms.

```
uses AnimatePlatform;

var
  AnimateCursor: TAnimate; // Create and destroy outside scope of Button2Click

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x,y : TArray<Integer>;
  i: Integer;
Const
  Points = 500;
begin
  SetLength(x,Points);
  SetLength(y,Points);
  for i := Low(x) to High(x) do
    x[i] := Self.Left + i*Self.Width div Points;
  for i := Low(y) to High(y) do
    y[i] := Self.Top + i*Self.Height div Points;
  AnimateCursor.Run(
    procedure(ix: Integer)
    begin
      SetCursorPos(x[ix],y[ix]);
    end,
    Low(x),High(x),10  // 10 ms is the smallest interval for a TTimer
  );
end;
```

Using the same approach with an anonymous thread (plus an optional event when animation is ready):

```
procedure AnimatedThread( aProc: TProc<Integer>;
                          FromValue, ToValue, AnimationDelay: Integer;
                          AReadyEvent : TNotifyEvent);
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      i: Integer;
      w : TSimpleEvent;
    begin
      w := TSimpleEvent.Create(Nil,False,False,'');
      try
        for i := FromValue to ToValue do begin
          TThread.Synchronize(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              aProc(i);
            end
          );
          w.WaitFor(AnimationDelay);
        end;
      finally
        w.Free;
      end;
      if Assigned(AReadyEvent) then
        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            AReadyEvent(Nil);
          end
        );
    end
  ).Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x,y : TArray<Integer>;
  i: Integer;
Const
  Points = 500;
begin
  SetLength(x,Points);
  SetLength(y,Points);
  for i := Low(x) to High(x) do
    x[i] := Self.Left + i*Self.Width div Points;
  for i := Low(y) to High(y) do
    y[i] := Self.Top + i*Self.Height div Points;
  AnimatedThread(
    procedure(ix: Integer)
    begin
      SetCursorPos(x[ix],y[ix]);
    end,
    Low(x),High(x),1,Nil // 1 ms delay
  );    
end;
```

**Note** that the thread based animations can have animation delays down to 1 ms.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something important in this question, but isn't that enough to use a timer ?

Comment: @TLama, yes that will work as well, but animation from a thread is more fun :-)

Comment: @LURD, when talking about animations, I was thinking about [`this approach`](http://pastebin.com/qPzG5SMD) ;-)

Comment: Just curious: Why do you copy the x and y parameters into local variables? Aren't the parameters captured by the anonymous procedure?

Comment: @HEARTWARE capture only available for local variables. Const params are not local variables. The params to MoveSlow are locals in the button handler and have left scope before the thread runs.

Comment: @HeartWare, as David said, only locals are captured. The compiler will nag you otherwise.

Comment: @TLama, added a `TTimer` based example, plus one more anonymous thread example. Note that smallest animation delay is 10 ms for the timer based, while a thread based animation can have delays down to 1ms.